# Angular2 - How do you console.log the current route?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am struggling to get this to work.

```
<li [class.active]="router.isRouteActive(router.generate(['/SomeRoute']))">
```

To bug test this I want to console.log the current route to see what the actual route is, but am not sure how to go about doing this in Angular2?

EDIT:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-pagination": "0.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.5",
    "cssnano": "^3.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^5.0.13",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.3",
    "precss": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What Angular2 / Router version? New RC.1 router or router-deprecated?

Comment: Hi Gunter, I have added my package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is the [location service](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Location-class.html#!#path-anchor)

> console.log(location.path())

Comment: location.pathname is the vanilla way, the angular way would have been using location.path() injecting the location service inside a component.
Anyway happy to have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RouteRegistry to find out information about other routes inside other component's code:

```
recognize(url: string, ancestorInstructions: Instruction[]) : Promise<Instruction>
```

> Given a URL and a parent component, return the most specific
>   instruction for navigating the application into the state specified by
>   the url

Official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteRegistry-class.html

Googd article on Angular2 router details: http://julienrenaux.fr/2015/12/25/angular2-series-routing/